# migrating code from dev to prodcution, is there a checklist

Tags: sql

I am currently trying to gather requirements to what is actually needed to move code from dev to production. These will mainly be SQL stored procedures and will be used to create reports in SSRS.

What are some things you guys do as a small (nothing major, or complicated) when moving code from dev to prod?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Test
2. Test
3. Test
4. back up everything you're going to replace
5. Test
6. Make sure that any modifications to underlying tables/views are migrated first
7. Use the "GENERATE SCRIPTS" option

Mind you, it's a good idea to have two databases: one for storing data and one for storing stored procedures. This way, you can create a third database to deploy your new stored procedures and views to so you can test them using live data without breaking anything for your users. We refer to it as a "staging" database.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a rollout script
2. Create a rollback script
3. Create Release note or deployment steps
4. Deploy the rollout in preprod or UAT env (following the release notes)and test
5. Deploy the rollback in preprod or UAT env  (following the release notes) and test
6. Take a DB backup if necessary
7. Deploy

Comment: whats a rollout script? Just a script that changes the server names (within the SQL stored procedure) to the prod server and stuff like that? 

Is it worth it to put all the SPROCS in version control?

Comment: Rollout script(s) will be the .sql files which will have changes of the SProcs.Yes everything has to be in version control